# await inside for loop and break for loop if condition matched

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, async-await, aws-lambda

I have an array. I need to iterate on array until data not found. once data found, I need to break for loop and just return those data.

```
const arrayData = ['1', '2', '3']

for (let i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
  data = await getSomeDataFromDB(arrayData[i]) // get data from DB
  if (data.length >= 1) { break } // If found break for loop else iterate again
}
return { items: data }
```

I have used the above code. Is this right way or any other better way to handle this kind of scenario?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks fine, though I'd use `for..of` instead, messing with manual indicies is ugly

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance or your suggestion

Comment: The code looks fine, is `getSomeDataFromDB` method returns a `promise`? `await` will work only if a `promise` is returned from the `method`. Also, wrap the code in a `try, catch` to handle the error

Comment: @ArUn yes it's a promise from dynamoDB. Thank you for your `try...catch` suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could omit the implicit global vairable by just returning from the loop:

```
for (const entry of arrayData) {
   const items = await getSomeDataFromDB(entry) // get data from DB
   if (items.length >= 1) 
      return { items };
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I have added part of the code. Actually the for loop is inside `if`. So, I must have to use break to get out from for loop.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using [for await of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

> The for await...of statement creates a loop iterating over async
>   iterable objects as well as on sync iterables, including: built-in
>   String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList),
>   TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined async/sync iterables. It
>   invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the
>   value of each distinct property of the object.

Comment: Lemme try this.